# I have added deeplink to my app, but the url that my app can open are not set by default in my app settings

Tags: android, flutter, applinks, flutter-deep-link

[image: Following image shows what my app setting looks like]

App links open perfectly but only issue is I have to set the url by clicking on add link and there in options that url is already present and i need to add that manually [image: When clicked on Add links button]

Here is the code for deep link in android manifest file

```
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="abc.myurl.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
```

Below is my assetLink.json's code

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.myapp.myapp",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["----myapp fingerprint-----"]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is related to hosting the assetlink.json file as I might have uploaded the keys of the app in developer mode. I will try and update if it works with release mode keys. If there is any other potential issue, please let me know

Comment: i am also facing the same issue in Flutter App. one more thing is that all the links/domains are shown as verified and working on the Google play console account

Comment: In my case i have solved the problem , the issue for my case was the assetlink file hosted was not in json format.

Answer (score 0):

put your assetLink.json file in root folder of your project in backend. path should be like this: "https://yourdomain.com/.well-know/assetlinks.json"